# Using percent symbol in token delimiter batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to get the ipV6 address from an interface using a batch file in windows7 (through netsh command), but I don't know how can I put the % as delimiter: This is why I have:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%A IN ('netsh int ipv6 show address "%IFACEWAN%" ^| FIND "Parameters"') DO (
    SET WANNIC.IPV6=%%B
)
```

And the result is:

```
WANNIC.IPV6=0000::aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd%12
```

but I want to remove the final "%12" from the result. I try to use % as delimiter, but it doesn't work:

```
| was unexpected at this time.
```

I try to use %% , ^%, and others, but I have no result.
How can I use this symbol as delimiter? There is any other way to remove this part?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to [double it](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) and left the space as the last delimiter:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=%% " %%A IN ('netsh int ipv6 show address "%IFACEWAN%" ^| FIND "Parameters"') DO (
    SET WANNIC.IPV6=%%B
)
```

E.g. This line works for me:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=%% " %%a in ('netsh int ipv6 show address^|find /i "infinite"') do echo %%e
```

Comment: I tried the %% but not put the space as the last delimiter, then it didn't work. I didn't think to change the order, this is the trick